# Zip codes for census data by state - acs

Tags: r

I'm using the acs package to get census data. In particular, I'm trying to get data for all the zip codes in the state of New Jersey.

The problem is that it seems I can only grab all of the zip codes in the US.

```
geo.make(zip.code = "*", check=T)
```

No other combination is working.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up importing the zip code list from another source for the area of interest and then merging the table with all the zip codes to the new one.

Answer (score 3):

This is impossible. Zip codes do not map to States. See: https://www.census.gov/geo/reference/webatlas/

Generally, the use of Zip codes as a geographical organizational unit should be discouraged. There are many problems with using zip codes, many of which are outlined on the [Zip Code Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ZIP_code). Most notably, while zip codes often have a geographic component they **do not** represent geographic regions; they correspond to address groups or delivery routes. As such, Zip codes can **overlap** state boundaries or even be artificial constructs with no geographic area.

Comment: Thanks. However, when you go to the acs website you can sort zip codes by state...

Comment: That's wonderful. But you can't do that in the acs package or in the acs API, which the acs package pulls from. So your comment is irrelevant.

Comment: Well, you said "This is impossible. Zip codes do not map to States", and apparently they do it in the acs website....
There is a lot of information that is only available in the zip code level, so while it's not ideal sometimes you have to use it. 
So, if it can be done in the website, I asked here if there's a way to do the same thing in r...

Comment: If you read the Census documents, which clearly you haven't, you will see that what I said is true. Zip codes via the census are known as "Zip Code Tabulation Areas". They are created by aggregating census blocks to approximate zip codes. However, they do not map back to states because they have to be aggregated from the national level of census blocks.... I've written thousands of lines of code on top of the `acs` package and read hundreds of pages of documentation. The information I'm providing is accurate.

Comment: My friend, I'm aware of this and appreciate you sharing your knowledge (I really do). Nonetheless, I do need this data in zip codes for one state. I'm sure someone will provide a package that can do this (by aggregating blocks like you said...), if it's not already exists... You can read million of pages, the fact remains that you can do this by state using the website (even if it is only an approximation).

Comment: Unless you provide a link validating your first comment, I'm not sure that I believe you.

Comment: Np. Go here [link](http://factfinder.census.gov/faces/nav/jsf/pages/searchresults.xhtml?refresh=t) 
Then, click on geographies, then in type, choose 5-digit zip code tabulated area, and then you will be able to select a state.
BTW, there is more data available in the zip codes scale than block groups. For example, 5-year data for the years 2011 and 2012 is only available at the zip-code level

Comment: It says: "You must have 20 reputation on Stack Overflow to talk here"
:/

Comment: Can you still open it?

Comment: Yes - thanks for the comment about the fully/partially within - that's good enough for the data that I am looking for (and again, I wish I was able to do this in r).
Now, when  you choose block groups for geography, and then go to the available variables (by closing the geographies window) - click on the dropdown menu of "show results from" - you will see that there's nothing available for 2011-2012. This is not the case when you choose the zip codes tabulation in geographies (which also provide a higher number of variables). Any idea why? Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can pull data via the acs package / acs API for 2011, 2012, 2013, and 2014. I can't comment on the American FactFinder resource.

Comment: If this answer has been helpful to you, I'd appreciate an upvote and accept--I've spent a considerable amount of time help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can get all zip codes of any area from `R` using `totalcensus` package. Follow the instruction to install and setup it https://github.com/GL-Li/totalcensus.   And here is [an example](https://gl-li.netlify.com/2017/12/28/use-totalcensus-package-to-determine-relationship-between-geographic-entities/) showing how to get census data of zip code.

Below is the code to get all zip codes in NJ:

```
# follow the instruction in the link to install the package, then
library(totalcensus)
zip_NJ <- read_decennial(
    year = 2010,
    states = "NJ",
    geo_headers = "ZCTA5",
    summary_level = "871"
)

# all zip codes in New Jersy
zip_NJ$ZCTA5

# 
#   [1] "07001" "07002" "07003" "07004" "07005" "07006" "07008" "07009" "07010" "07011" "07012" "07013" "07014"
#  [14] "07016" "07017" "07018" "07020" "07021" "07022" "07023" "07024" "07026" "07027" "07028" "07029" "07030"
#  [27] "07031" "07032" "07033" "07034" "07035" "07036" "07039" "07040" "07041" "07042" "07043" "07044" "07045"
#  [40] "07046" "07047" "07050" "07052" "07054" "07055" "07057" "07058" "07059" "07060" "07062" "07063" "07064"
#  [53] "07065" "07066" "07067" "07068" "07069" "07070" "07071" "07072" "07073" "07074" "07075" "07076" "07077"
#  [66] "07078" "07079" "07080" "07081" "07082" "07083" "07086" "07087" "07088" "07090" "07092" "07093" "07094"
#  [79] "07095" "07102" "07103" "07104" "07105" "07106" "07107" "07108" "07109" "07110" "07111" "07112" "07114"
#  [92] "07201" "07202" "07203" "07204" "07205" "07206" "07208" "07302" "07304" "07305" "07306" "07307" "07310"
# [105] "07311" "07401" "07403" "07405" "07407" "07410" "07416" "07417" "07418" "07419" "07420" "07421" "07422"
# [118] "07423" "07424" "07430" "07432" "07435" "07436" "07438" "07439" "07440" "07442" "07444" "07446" "07450"
# [131] "07452" "07456" "07457" "07458" "07460" "07461" "07462" "07463" "07465" "07470" "07480" "07481" "07495"
# [144] "07501" "07502" "07503" "07504" "07505" "07506" "07508" "07512" "07513" "07514" "07522" "07524" "07601"
# [157] "07603" "07604" "07605" "07606" "07607" "07608" "07620" "07621" "07624" "07626" "07627" "07628" "07630"
# [170] "07631" "07632" "07640" "07641" "07642" "07643" "07644" "07645" "07646" "07647" "07648" "07649" "07650"
# [183] "07652" "07656" "07657" "07660" "07661" "07662" "07663" "07666" "07670" "07675" "07676" "07677" "07701"
# [196] "07702" "07703" "07704" "07711" "07712" "07716" "07717" "07718" "07719" "07720" "07721" "07722" "07723"
# [209] "07724" "07726" "07727" "07728" "07730" "07731" "07732" "07733" "07734" "07735" "07737" "07738" "07739"
# [222] "07740" "07746" "07747" "07748" "07750" "07751" "07753" "07755" "07756" "07757" "07758" "07760" "07762"
# [235] "07764" "07801" "07803" "07820" "07821" "07822" "07823" "07825" "07826" "07827" "07828" "07830" "07832"
# [248] "07833" "07834" "07836" "07838" "07840" "07842" "07843" "07846" "07847" "07848" "07849" "07850" "07851"
# [261] "07852" "07853" "07856" "07857" "07860" "07863" "07865" "07866" "07869" "07870" "07871" "07874" "07876"
# [274] "07878" "07880" "07881" "07882" "07885" "07901" "07920" "07921" "07922" "07924" "07926" "07927" "07928"
# [287] "07930" "07931" "07932" "07933" "07934" "07935" "07936" "07939" "07940" "07945" "07946" "07950" "07960"
# [300] "07961" "07970" "07974" "07976" "07977" "07979" "07980" "07981" "08001" "08002" "08003" "08004" "08005"
# [313] "08006" "08007" "08008" "08009" "08010" "08011" "08012" "08014" "08015" "08016" "08019" "08020" "08021"
# [326] "08022" "08023" "08026" "08027" "08028" "08029" "08030" "08031" "08033" "08034" "08035" "08036" "08037"
# [339] "08038" "08039" "08041" "08042" "08043" "08045" "08046" "08048" "08049" "08050" "08051" "08052" "08053"
# [352] "08054" "08055" "08056" "08057" "08059" "08060" "08061" "08062" "08063" "08064" "08065" "08066" "08067"
# [365] "08068" "08069" "08070" "08071" "08072" "08073" "08074" "08075" "08077" "08078" "08079" "08080" "08081"
# [378] "08083" "08084" "08085" "08086" "08087" "08088" "08089" "08090" "08091" "08092" "08093" "08094" "08095"
# [391] "08096" "08097" "08098" "08102" "08103" "08104" "08105" "08106" "08107" "08108" "08109" "08110" "08201"
# [404] "08202" "08203" "08204" "08205" "08210" "08212" "08215" "08217" "08221" "08223" "08224" "08225" "08226"
# [417] "08230" "08232" "08234" "08240" "08241" "08242" "08243" "08244" "08246" "08247" "08248" "08251" "08260"
# [430] "08270" "08302" "08310" "08311" "08312" "08314" "08316" "08317" "08318" "08319" "08320" "08321" "08322"
# [443] "08323" "08324" "08326" "08327" "08328" "08329" "08330" "08332" "08340" "08341" "08343" "08344" "08345"
# [456] "08346" "08348" "08349" "08350" "08352" "08353" "08360" "08361" "08401" "08402" "08403" "08406" "08501"
# [469] "08502" "08505" "08510" "08511" "08512" "08514" "08515" "08518" "08520" "08525" "08527" "08528" "08530"
# [482] "08533" "08534" "08535" "08536" "08540" "08542" "08550" "08551" "08553" "08554" "08555" "08558" "08559"
# [495] "08560" "08561" "08562" "08608" "08609" "08610" "08611" "08618" "08619" "08620" "08628" "08629" "08638"
# [508] "08640" "08641" "08648" "08690" "08691" "08701" "08720" "08721" "08722" "08723" "08724" "08730" "08731"
# [521] "08732" "08733" "08734" "08735" "08736" "08738" "08740" "08741" "08742" "08750" "08751" "08752" "08753"
# [534] "08755" "08757" "08758" "08759" "08801" "08802" "08804" "08805" "08807" "08808" "08809" "08810" "08812"
# [547] "08816" "08817" "08820" "08821" "08822" "08823" "08824" "08825" "08826" "08827" "08828" "08829" "08830"
# [560] "08831" "08832" "08833" "08835" "08836" "08837" "08840" "08844" "08846" "08848" "08850" "08852" "08853"
# [573] "08854" "08857" "08858" "08859" "08861" "08863" "08865" "08867" "08869" "08872" "08873" "08876" "08879"
# [586] "08880" "08882" "08884" "08886" "08887" "08889" "08890" "08901" "08902" "08904"
```